# Getting only `false` as a return value

Tags: java

When I test the following test cases:

```
 public void put_remove2(IMiniMap<Integer,Double> map){
        int [] ia   = { 8,  6,  7,  5,  3,  0,  9,-86,-75,-30,-90};
        double[] da = {.6,.07,.50,.33,.00,.90,.86,.75,.30,.90,.08};
        for(int i=0; i<ia.length; i++){
          assertEquals(null, map.put(ia[i], da[i]));
        }

        int expectSize = ia.length;
        assertEquals(expectSize, map.size());

        int [] remove = { 7, 1, 6, 4};
        for(int rdx : remove){
          assertEquals(true, map.contains(ia[rdx]));
          assertEquals(new Double(da[rdx]), map.get(ia[rdx]));
          assertEquals(new Double(da[rdx]), map.remove(ia[rdx]));
          assertEquals(false, map.contains(ia[rdx]));
          assertEquals(null, map.get(ia[rdx]));
          expectSize--;
          assertEquals(expectSize,map.size());
        }
      }
```

I'm getting result `false` but I should get `true` and whatever number I put in ia[..] I get `false`. The bug is hiding somewhere in `indexOf(K key)` or `contains(K key)` method, I assume.

Main class:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IMiniMap<Integer,Double> map = new FastGetListMM<Integer,Double>();
        int [] ia   = { 8,  6,  7,  5,  3,  0,  9,-86,-75,-30,-90};

        boolean check = map.contains(ia[4]);
        System.out.println(check);
    }
}
```

Separate class:

```
    public class FastGetListMM<K,V> extends AbstractListMM<K,V>
    {
       public final Comparator<K> cmp; 

     public FastGetListMM()
     {
        super(new ArrayList<K>(), new ArrayList<V>());
        cmp = null;
     }
     public FastGetListMM(Comparator<K> cmp)
     {
        this.cmp = cmp;
     }

     public boolean contains(K key)
     {
        int pos = this.indexOf(key);
        if(pos < 0)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
     }


     public void ensureComparable(K key)
     {
      if(!(key instanceof Comparable) && cmp == null) 
          throw new RuntimeException("The key is not instance of Comparable or comparator object is null");
     }
   public int indexOf(K key) 
   {
       ensureComparable(key);
       int foundIndex = Collections.binarySearch(keys, key, cmp);

       return foundIndex;
   }
}
```

Comment: In your example your `map` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your not feeding the `map`. You created `map` instance, then feeded `ia` variable and checking `map.contains()`.

`map.contains(<key>)` will look for the keys in the map. In your case no `keys` present in the `map`. so it always returns `false`.

Comment: I do not think so. `K key` is of generic type so it should be right, @Dilip

Comment: @John look at the `main` method. You create a map, but you are not putting any data in the map (unless you are doing that in other code that you are not showing). So, ofcourse the map is then going to tell you that it doesn't contain the element you're looking for.

Comment: @John As per the code you sent, i haven't seen any `map.put(K,V)` (i.e your not putting any data into `map`).

Comment: @Dilip, my bad guys I've updated the test cases in the code. Take a look